# I want to call validate_even method during validation of username but it shows name 'validate_even' is not defined

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

**I am stuck to create custom validation for username my forms.py**

```
from .models import User
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from PIL import Image
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
   email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')
   first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False,                                     help_text='Optional.')
   last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
   phone = forms.CharField(max_length=30, help_text='Phone number', required=False)
   # vv = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='custom', required=False)
   picture = forms.ImageField()
   username = forms.CharField(error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that username already exists.'}, help_text='required.',validators=[validate_even],  max_length=150),
   class Meta:
      model  = get_user_model()
      fields =('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'phone','picture')
```

**my models.py is**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from PIL import Image
from django.contrib.auth.validators import UnicodeUsernameValidator
class User(AbstractUser):
   pp = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
   xx = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
   dd = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
   vv = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
   picture = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'uploads/', default = 'var/www/html/typo3/uploads/no-img.jpg')
   username = models.CharField(error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that username already exists.'}, help_text='baal required.',validators=[validate_even],  max_length=150),
```

**my validators.py is**

```
import re
from django.core import validators
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
def validate_even(value):
   if value % 2 != 0:
     raise ValidationError(
        _('%(value)s is not an even number'),
        params={'value': value},
    )
```

**What mistake I had made, I can not understand . How to call my custom method in validotrs?**

Comment: Did you remember to include the method into your form file? I don't see an import statement.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Django is a Python framework so you're obviously expected to learn Python if you want to use Django. I kindly suggest you take time to do the whole official Python tutorial before anything else, else you will spend your time posting here for really basics stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line at the begin of models.py and forms.py:

```
from .validators import validate_even
```

Comment: ok I did exactly . Now it shows Unknown field(s) (username) specified for User

Comment: AbstractUser include a `username` field, remove the username field line in your models.py and then `./manage.py makemigrations && ./manage.py migrate` and  runserver again.

Comment: Hi I want to use custom validator and custom help_text for username field. If I remove it from models.py then how can I use custom validation for username field?

Comment: @ARUNIMADAS your issue with "Unknown field(s) (username) specified for User" is totally unrelated, please post a new question.

Comment: @ARUNIMADAS validation is userally set at forms.py, not models.py